# Prisma db seed not working on a remote supabase instance

Tags: typescript, prisma, supabase, seeding

I am working on a Nextjs project and would like to build a preview environment on Vercel where I use supabase (remote postgres) for database.

I would like to run `prisma db seed` in the preview environment as well but I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while running the seed command:
Error: Command was killed with SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault): ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts
```

The build command to deploy migrations (`prisma migrate deploy`) was succeeded in the vercel's preview environment and the database schema is exactly the same as the local one.

As specified in the prisma document, I added following property in the `package.json`

```json
"prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
}
```

Then I changed the DATABASE_URL in .env to that of supabase and ran `prisma db seed`, resulting the error.

So I tried to run `seed.ts` directly with a lot more memory allocated with this command:
`NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096" yarn ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts` but I still face the segmentation fault error.

Note that prisma version is 4.10.1, node version is 18.12.1

Comment: What is your node version?
I can see a similar issue: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/13641

Comment: Are you able to run `prisma db push` ?

Comment: As discussed in the github issue I downgraded node version to 16.14.1 and it worked! Thank you very much.